# Creating columns from a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Sample Data]

```
SELECT TOP 20
        TMPPO.PurchaseOrder ,
        TMPPO.LineItem ,
        ASLD.SignatureDate ,
        ASLD.SignatureTime ,
        ASLD.Operator ,
        ASLD.Variable ,
        ASLD.VariableDesc ,
        ASLD.VarNumericValue
FROM    #POAMENDMENTS TMPPO
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[AdmSignatureLogDet] ASLD ON TMPPO.TransactionId = ASLD.TransactionId
                                                              AND TMPPO.SignatureDate = ASLD.SignatureDate
                                                              AND TMPPO.SignatureTime = ASLD.SignatureTime
WHERE   YEAR(TMPPO.SignatureDate) = 2013
        AND MONTH(TMPPO.SignatureDate) = 08
        AND VariableDesc IN ( 'Previous foreign price', 'Previous price',
                              'Foreign price', 'Price' )
ORDER BY PurchaseOrder ,
        LineItem
```

I have the following table but don't want to return the records as per below.
Under the column heading  Variable Desc I have Foreign Price, Previous foreign pirce, previous price and price I would like to make these as headings the replace Variable, Variable Desc and VarNumberic.
So e.g. for the first line would be

```
Purchase Order LineItem SignatureDate SignatureTime Operator PrevFPrice FPrice PrevPrice Price
002074         0001     2013-02-23     9523598       UPOFA0  19.68      21.51   19.68    21.51
004931         0001     2013-08-09     7485253       PVWYK0  980.00     840.00  980.00   840.00
```

Sorry but is difficult to put sample data here no idea how to...

Is this possible?

@Bummi it provides me data like this, why is Purchase Order 005331 duplicating so many times when in essence according to the original sample data it changed only 2 times according to date and time
[image]

Comment: Peraphs you want to use an alias for your column name?

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with MySQL does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am understanding you are looking for a join over your first query

```
;With CTE as
(
SELECT TOP 20 TMPPO.PurchaseOrder, TMPPO.LineItem, ASLD.SignatureDate,ASLD.SignatureTime,ASLD.Operator, ASLD.Variable, ASLD.VariableDesc, ASLD.VarNumericValue  FROM #POAMENDMENTS TMPPO
LEFT OUTER JOIN [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[AdmSignatureLogDet] ASLD ON TMPPO.TransactionId = ASLD.TransactionId and TMPPO.SignatureDate = ASLD.SignatureDate and TMPPO.SignatureTime = ASLD.SignatureTime   
WHERE YEAR(TMPPO.SignatureDate) = 2013
and MONTH(TMPPO.SignatureDate) = 08 
and VariableDesc IN ('Previous foreign price','Previous price','Foreign price','Price')
ORDER BY PurchaseOrder, LineItem  
)
Select c1.PurchaseOrder,c1.LineItem,c1.SignatureDate,c1.SignatureTime,c1.Operator
,c1.VarNumericValue as [Previous foreign price]
,c2.VarNumericValue as [Previous price]
,c3.VarNumericValue as [Foreign price]
,c4.VarNumericValue as [Price]

FROM CTE c1
JOIN CTE c2 on c2.PurchaseOrder=c1.PurchaseOrder and c2.VariableDesc='Previous price'    
               and c2.LineItem=c1.LineItem and c2.SignatureDate=c1.SignatureDate and c2.SignatureTime=c1.SignatureTime
JOIN CTE c3 on c3.PurchaseOrder=c1.PurchaseOrder and c3.VariableDesc='Foreign price'    
               and c3.LineItem=c1.LineItem and c3.SignatureDate=c1.SignatureDate and c3.SignatureTime=c1.SignatureTime
JOIN CTE c4 on c4.PurchaseOrder=c1.PurchaseOrder and c4.VariableDesc='Price'    
               and c4.LineItem=c1.LineItem and c4.SignatureDate=c1.SignatureDate and c4.SignatureTime=c1.SignatureTime
Where c1.VariableDesc='Previous foreign price'
```

Comment: I placed the result sent as a screen shot to the top. Its duplicating some data...

Comment: So e.g. PO 005331 had to changes 1. @ time 9530687 from PreviousForeign Price 85 to 114 and then @ time 9533838 changed from PreviousForeign Price 114 to 28.61 and some of ur return results don't correspond.

Comment: @user1546143 sorry, did not read your data carefully enough, forgot some conditions for the joins.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 'AS' to rename your columns

SELECT something AS somethingelse